# Automapper configuration falls short on partial class?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have following `AccountDetailRecord` class to be mapped to the `AccountDetailDto` with the following configuration but somehow I am missing something in mapping the partial classes.

```
services
.AddSingleton(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<AccountDetailRecord, AccountDetailDto>().ReverseMap();
    cfg.CreateMap<AddressRecord, AccountDetailDto.AddressDto>().ReverseMap();
}).CreateMapper())
```

**source**:

```
internal class AccountDetailRecord
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
internal class AddressRecord
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AddressTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**destination:**

```
public partial class AccountDetailDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EstablishmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AddressDto> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class AccountDetailDto
{
    public class AddressDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public AddressTypeDto AddressType { get; set; }
    }
}

public partial class AccountDetailDto
{
    public class AddressTypeDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but in the result the values of the `AddressType`.
what am I missing in configuration?

Comment: There is no `AddressType` property to use in the source of your mapping, ho do you expect the mapper should know how to map your custom type?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma that's Reverse Mapping and Unflattening. please look at the example in http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Comment: As the documentation says: *Unflattening is only configured for `ReverseMap`. If you want unflattening, you must configure `Entity` -> `Dto` then call `ReverseMap` to create an unflattening type map configuration from the `Dto` -> `Entity`.*

Comment: I'm doing the same but my class names are using the suffix dto in backward manner. please don't get confused by the naming of the classes.

Comment: I'm not talking about the name of the classes **at all**. You did not configure any custom mapper for your `AddressType` property, so your configuration will try to unflatten your `AccountDetailDto.AddressDto` **into** `AddressRecord`, but you want the **opposite**. Unflattening **will happen only on the reverse map**. To achieve what you want you need to swap your types: `cfg.CreateMap<AccountDetailDto.AddressDto, AddressRecord>().ReverseMap();`

Comment: oh my .. that was a silly mistake! thank you @FedericoDipuma. indeed you are right! now it works. :) if you put it in answer, I will mark it as a answer to the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your classes properties, what you need is to reverse the mapping, so AutoMapper will be able to unflatten your `AddressTypeId` and `AddressTypeDescription` source properties into an `AddressTypeDto` object.

As the [documentation states](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html):

> Unflattening is only configured for `ReverseMap`. If you want
>   unflattening, you must configure `Entity` -> `Dto` then call `ReverseMap` to
>   create an unflattening type map configuration from the `Dto` -> `Entity`

So you simply need to swap your mapping declaration to:

```
cfg.CreateMap<AccountDetailDto.AddressDto, AddressRecord>().ReverseMap();
```